# Is it correct to put bound variables inside logical functions?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I have to translate this sentence to predicate logic:

Every animal either likes to eat all plants or all animals much smaller than itself that like to eat some plants.

Clearly I have to distinguish animals that like to eat some- and all plants.
I define the function eats(x,y)=x likes to eat y.

So is it correct to write something like eats(x, all(y)[whatever(y)])?Can a bound variable be inside a function like this?

Comment: For example : "Every animal likes to eat all plants" is $\forall x [Animal(x) \to \forall y (Plant(y) \to Likes(x,y))]$

Comment: indeed, your version looks way better, thanks